# Python aiohttp module: ambiguous .content attribute

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp, python-aiofiles

Here is a little code snippet:

```
import aiohttp
import aiofiles

async def fetch(url):
    # starting a session
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        # starting a get request
        async with session.get(url) as response:
            # getting response content
            content = await response.content
            return content
 
async def save_file(file_name, content):
    async with aiofiles.open(f'./binary/{file_name}', 'wb') as f:
      while True:
            chunk = content.read(1024)
            if not chunk:
                break
            f.write(chunk)
```

I am trying to download some binary files using the `aiohttp` library and then passing them to a coroutine using `aiofiles` library to write the file in the disk.
I have read the [documentation](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_quickstart.html#binary-response-content) but still couldn't figure out if I can pass `content = await response.content` or is it closed when the handle `async with..` is closed? Because on a [secondary blog](https://dzone.com/articles/an-intro-to-aiohttp), I found:

> According to aiohttp’s documentation, because the response object was created in a context manager, it technically calls release() implicitly.

Which confuses me, should I embed the logic of the second function inside the `response` handle or is my logic correct?

Comment: I believe you can’t await just `response.content`. You need to await `response.content.read()`. If the files you’re downloading are large, you’ll want to pass a chunk size to `read`.

Comment: @dirn if I don't pass the chunk size to read, the whole file will be captured? And if I pass a chunk size, how will the whole file be passed to the second function that writes the file on the disk since the variable `content = await response.content.read(1024)` will only have a single chunk ?

Comment: That is correct. You’d have to pass the chunks to the function that writes them to disk. It would then append each chunk to the file. But if you aren’t concerned about the size of these files fitting into memory, then you don’t need to split them up like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [user4815162342](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1600898/user4815162342)'s code I could find a solution by parellelizing the fetch and write coroutines. I would've checked his code as the accepted solution but since I had to add some code to make it work, here it is:

```
# fetch binary from server
async def fetch(url):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(url) as response:
            async for chunk in response.content.iter_chunked(4096):
                yield chunk

# write binary function
async def save_file(file_name, chunk_iter):
    list(map(create_dir_tree, list_binary_sub_dirs))
    async with aiofiles.open(f'./binary/bin_ts/{file_name}', 'wb') as f:
        async for chunk in chunk_iter:
            await f.write(chunk)
    

async def main(urls):
    tasks = []
    for url in urls:
        print('running on sublist')
        file_name = url.rpartition('/')[-1]
        request_ts = fetch(url)
        tasks.append(save_file(file_name, request_ts))
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

asyncio.run(main(some_list_of_urls))
```

Comment: Note that you probably want to create the session in `main()` and pass it down to `fetch` as an argument.

Comment: @user4815162342 how would that be more efficient?

Comment: It would allow reuse of TCP connections, for example, but also other data that can be persisted between invocations (think cached DNS lookups, things like that). By creating a new session, you are basically reinitializing the whole library from scratch for every individual request.

Answer (score 1):

The async context manager will close the resources related to the request, so if you return from the function, you have to make sure you've read everything of interest. So you have two options:

1. read the entire response into memory, e.g. with `content = await response.read()` or, if the file doesn't fit into memory (and also if you want to speed things up by reading and writing in parallel)
2. use a queue or an async iterator to parallelize reading and writing.

Here is an untested implementation of #2:

```
async def fetch(url):
    # return an async generator over contents of URL
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(url) as response:
            # getting response content in chunks no larger than 4K
            for chunk in response.content.iter_chunked(4096):
                yield chunk
 
async def save_file(file_name, content_iter):
    async with aiofiles.open(f'./binary/{file_name}', 'wb') as f:
        for chunk in content_iter:
            f.write(chunk)  # maybe you need to await this?

async def main():
    save_file(file_name, fetch(url))
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain it clearly, I would've accepted your solution as the answer but I had to add some code on top of it.